# Cannot read properties of undefined when filtering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9

I have an issue, I've already searched YouTube, etc but no result is successful.

This is my code

```js
const deleteProduct = id => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      axios.delete(`/api/product/${id}`).then(response => {
        products.value.data = products.value.data.filter(
          product => product.id !== id
        )
        Swal.fire('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success')
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Another file in my UI just like:

```html
<a href="" class="pl-2" @click.prevent="deleteProduct(product.id)">
  <font-awesome-icon
    :icon="['fas', 'trash-can']"
    beat-fade
    style="color: #f20202"
  />
</a>
```

Result from this code is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
> at ListProduct.vue:29:67

filter is undefined, maybe someone can help me with this problem

I tried to write code to delete some item in my products and result should be pushed on data / table list with success alert, but it never happens because console says filter is undefined

Comment: No it's not `filter` that is undefined it's (based on the code you show us) `products.value.data` that is undefined.

Comment: The reason the error mentions filter is because the code is being executed as `products.value.undefined.filter()`.  `filter` is not a property of `undefined`.  There is also nothing in the rest of your code to suggest `data` is a valid property, so there's no other debugging or help that can be offered here without more code or explanation.